# Mudar escala de gráfico de série temporal

Tags: r

Estou fazendo um gráfico de uma série temporal de 84 meses, mas queria mudar a escala do **eixo x para de 6 em 6 meses** para facilitar a interpretação, mas não consigo.

```
notif <- ts(not)
plot(notif, col=2, xlab="Tempo (meses)")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para tentar mudar a escala do eixo x introduzi o seguinte código:

```
plot(notif, col=2, xlab="Tempo (meses)", axis(1, seq(1, 84, 6)))
```

Me dá a seguinte mensagem:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
>     'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 0):

Duas coisas:

1. Se o que te interessa é apenas o número de meses e não as datas em si, não precisa converter para `ts`. Como série temporal, não conseguirá definir os intervalos usando sequência de números inteiros.
2. `axis` vai fora do `plot`. Primeiro crie um gráfico sem os eixos, depois adicione-os manualmente.

Como não forneceu um exemplo dos seus dados, estou usando a base `ldeaths`, que vem inclusa no R.

```
not <- as.vector(ldeaths)

plot(not, type = "l", col = 2, xlab = "Tempo (meses)", axes = FALSE)
axis(1, seq(1, length(not), 6))
axis(2)
box()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se precisa das datas, uma boa opção para controlar facilmente a exibição é usar `ggplot2` em conjunto com o pacote `ggfortify`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

autoplot(ldeaths, colour = "red") + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b/%y", breaks = "6 months") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]